UsageError: Line magic function '%rm' not found
I am getting this error on the following line in my .ipynb file
%rm -rf LLaMA-Factory

I am using Python 3.9 version
I am experimenting with all the possible ways to to fine-tune LLMs. The code that I have is working on colab. I want to replicate that locally.

That's not Python, it's shell, specifically the rm command.
% is a common shell prefix and is not part of the command.
In Python notebooks the way to run shell commands is usually the ! prefix, as in:
! rm -rf ...

Note: Be extremely careful when using -rf as this can easily remove entire swaths of your drive with absolutely no confirmation needed.
